# execute trigger in case of formula field update

Tags: apex, lightning, administration

Hi I have a formula field in objectA. based upon objectB's field I am updating the formula field on objectA. After update I have to perform some logic on objectA. As formula field update does not trigger any DML so How can I achieve this? Pls suggest.

Comment: Formula field recalculates when you are viewing it. You can try use Process Builder for updating objectA instead of formula field

Comment: The trigger will fire only when there is a DML statement firing , when the value of the formula field changes no such thing happens , so in order to fire the trigger, update field on objectA using Process builder or trigger.

Comment: @IgorVasylevskyi - you should post that as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula field recalculates when you are viewing it. You can try use Process Builder (or record triggered Flow) for updating objectA instead of formula field and trigger will be fired